# MariaDB Encryption at rest - provide key from app

Tags: encryption, mariadb

In the past, I use Sybase anywhere db as my db server. I can encrypt the whole db with password, and from my application, i provide password inside connection string to gain access to server.

I want to use the same / similar scenario with mariaDB.

Suppose i have mariadb with encryption at rest.

1- can i provide key from my application directly?

or build wcf service that mariadb call to get the key it needs when starting

2- can i prevent resetting admin password on encrypted db?

3- Is there any other dbs that support this scenario ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- can I provide key from my application directly?

Not at the moment. The [encryption key API](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/encryption-plugin-api/) is written around a global service. While an application could push a key into a global table, it doesn't sound like the most secure of approaches.

> or build wcf service that mariadb call to get the key it needs when starting

Yes. Definitely. Implement the above referenced API or [there is a presentation on writing encryption plugins in Rust](https://mariadb.org/plugin-design-with-rust/) this week.

> 2- can I prevent resetting admin password on encrypted db?

The encryption-AT-REST is providing confidentialy protection when shut down (at rest). When not running, without the encryption keys, it would be impossible to change the password so something that is recognised on startup. Without sufficient filesystem protections of MariaDB's data there nothing preventing destruction of data, but if this possible, you've got larger problems.

A running service has no protection against any user resetting their own password or a privileged user resetting another users password.

> 3- Is there any other dbs that support this scenario ?

This is out of bound of the questions that SO will answer.

Comment: Just to be sure: If i google "mariadb reset root password", i got how to do it procedure.
You said that there is no way to prevent / disable this procedure . Right?
can you please comment on why this procedure exists on most famous dbs. what is the point of password, if it can be reset easily ?

Comment: As system tables are Aria, those can be encrypted to. [You can check](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aria-encryption-overview/#determining-whether-a-table-is-encrypted). So I bet the google procedure hasn't tried to real with a encryption and that key not being available.

Comment: thanks. I will try to do [reset root password procedure] on encrypted mariadb and see if it will success of fail